# Spring hibernate unwanted timezone adjustment

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, date

I have a simple service that takes a date in as a String (amongst other fields) and saves it to a mySql database. I am using Spring Boot with Hibernate.
 If I post JSON with `{"expenseDate":"04/02/2017"}` the date that is being captured after the jackson mapping is "2017-04-01 19:00:00".

Incidentally, if I look at the row in the database, the date is "2017-04-02" just as I would expect. When I query the service, the date that comes back in the json is correct, but when I dump out the rows from the database, they all return the correct day minus six hours.

I live in the central time zone, so my guess is that the date in the database is UTC and Spring is taking six hours off for being in central time.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/expenses")
public ResponseEntity<Expense> submitExpense(@RequestBody Expense expense) throws BadHttpRequest {
    expenseService.saveExpense(expense);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(expense, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Expense {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
Integer id;
Double cost;
String location;
String expenseType;
String description;

@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
Date expenseDate;
```

I tried `@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy", timezone = "UTC")` on the date field but it changed nothing.

I also tried constructing the date from the view using the date parts and passing it as a long down to the service, but the result is the same. clearly I'm missing something excruciatingly vital and, likely, simple.

any thoughts?

Comment: When you pass 04/02/2017 in the JSON input, which timezone is that date supposed to be in? Is the consumer of your service supposed to pass the date in UTC?

Comment: probably a bit naive on my part, but I would have just assumed the value of that date without any modification, so a truncated date that would have the value of what was passed in. And that's exactly what it looks like in the database, so it *looks* like what I'm doing is right, except nothing adds up right and when I intercept the objects the actual value is off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the "timezone" to whatever timezone you expect the incoming date to be in.

```
public class Data {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy", timezone="GMT-04:00")
    Date date;

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Data data = mapper.readValue("{\"date\" : \"04/02/2017\"}", Data.class);
        System.out.println(data.date);
    }
}
```

> Output

Sun Apr 02 00:00:00 EDT 2017

```
// I am located in EDT
```

If I assume the incoming date is in UTC

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy", timezone="UTC")
Date date;
```

> Output

Sat Apr 01 20:00:00 EDT 2017

By default it appears to be considering the date as UTC. In your case if you are in CST you should consider setting Central Time timezone (I believe **US/Central**).

**`Note`**
If your date inputs can come from clients in different timezones that will be another discussion. You will most likely have to define a contract that client enters a date in a particular timezone OR explicitly specify a timezone as additional input OR have your client side (if one exists) do a conversion to a specific timezone that your server-side expects.

Comment: This was a great help - combined with the answer below. I had set the timezone to UTC on the db connection property and on the jsonformat for the entity - changing it to my local timezone fixed the issue. now it's all ringing a bell, if I had not set the db parameter and let spring use the default timezone this wouldn't have happened

Answer (score 1):

There is a database connection url parameter called serverTimezone you may need put.

Comment: this was part of the issue - I had the property set on the db url as UTC - I needed to change it to my local timezone. If i left it alone to use the default for the database and had spring use the default it would have been fine. thanks!